# user != users.get_current_user()

Tags: google-app-engine, if-statement, python-2.7

**Update:** 
The only answer yet given is **not** helping me. The code works as desired on my local system but does not work in the deployed Python app. This is a series problem for me. Please give this question a serious second look.

Here is some simplified code to show what is happening. When the simplified code is put into the interactive console for the SDK, it always prints out `Hello, schott.brian`, but in the deployed app its like it prints out `no match`. What's up with that?

```
user = "schott.brian"
name = "schott.brian"

if user and user == name:
     print "Hello, " + user
else:
     print "no match"
```

Here is my code. Notice the second `if` checks `if user and (user == person.user):`

```
user = users.get_current_user()
ID_id = self.request.get("ID", None)
ID_id = ''.join(ID_id.split())
key = db.Key.from_path("PQ", ID_id)
person = PQ.get(key)
if person: #person's ID DOES exist already
     logging.info("6 person %s" % person.user )
     logging.info("6 key %s" % key )
     logging.info("6 ID_id %s" % ID_id )
     logging.info("6 user %s" % user )
     if user and (user == person.user):
          # never get here on gae, but works on sdk
     else:
          # always gets to here by mistake on gae, but works on SDKs
          logging.info("7 user %s" % user )
          logging.info("7 person %s" % person.user )
```

Here are the logs for that code on gae and even though user exists and 
(user == person.user), that if clause is NOT succeeding. Can you tell me why? Does one of the two really include gmail.com and the other does not?

```
2012-07-17 15:39:19.993 6 person schott.brian
I 2012-07-17 15:39:19.993 6 key ag1zfnBhcnRpY2lwb2xschMLEgJQUSILY29kZUJTY2hvdHQM
I 2012-07-17 15:39:19.993 6 ID_id codeBSchott
I 2012-07-17 15:39:19.993 6 user schott.brian
I 2012-07-17 15:39:19.993 7 user schott.brian
I 2012-07-17 15:39:19.994 7 person schott.brian
```

Comment: Moishe, that produces the same result. But thanks. Other ideas? For example is it the other part of the if clause (if user) that is the problem? Btw, I thought users.get_current_user() *was* the user ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`user.get_current_user()` returns an object. Printing the user casts it to a string, so maybe you want to do something like:

```
if user and (str(user) == str(person.user)):
```

but you're actually better off comparing user ids, rather than string representations of user objects.

Comment: Your answer was correct, but not adequate. I have to `str(person.user)`, also.

Comment: Cool! I would really encourage you to use user.id for comparison, though.